# How can I make a download page?

Tags: php, html, download

I'm tring to make a upload service, but what I'm asking myself for days is, how can I make a download page like the modern upload services? Now I can download my file directly when I click "Download" but I want a page with a free and a premium version to download the file.

Below you can see how I make my download URL:

```
protected function get_download_url($file_name, $version = null, $direct = false) {
    if (!$direct && $this->options['download_via_php']) {
        $url = $this->options['script_url']
            .$this->get_query_separator($this->options['script_url'])
            .$this->get_singular_param_name()
            .'='.rawurlencode($file_name);
        if ($version) {
            $url .= '&version='.rawurlencode($version);
        }
        return $url.'&download=1';
    }
    if (empty($version)) {
        $version_path = '';
    } else {
        $version_url = @$this->options['image_versions'][$version]['upload_url'];
        if ($version_url) {
            return $version_url.$this->get_user_path().rawurlencode($file_name);
        }
        $version_path = rawurlencode($version).'/';
    }
    return $this->options['upload_url'].$this->get_user_path()
        .$version_path.rawurlencode($file_name);
}
```

To show the download link I use;

```
<p class="name">
            <form name='download' id='downloadForm' method='POST' action='download.php'> //Tried to use a form and get the POST value, but didn't work
                {% if (file.url) { %}<p>{%=file.name%}</p>
                    <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" {%=file.thumbnailUrl?'data-gallery':''%} name="{%=file.name%}" onclick="document.forms['download'].submit();">Download</a>
                {% } else { %}
                    <span>{%=file.name%}</span>
                {% } %}
            </p>
            </form>
```

Any help is appreciated, I am struggling for days..

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Do make the download option directly, you should point the file directly in the `href` tag, and do have 2 different type of pages i.e., free and premium you shall differentiate it by unique code system i.e., for free any one can download and for premium the user should enter the given Copoun code or any unique code that u provide. Or if you differentiate it by url , then that's fine

Comment: But when I have a similar page, how can I bring the file.url/file.name with me? I tried it out with the form, but Didn't work. Couldn't get the data.

Comment: You should point it directly.. i.e., if you file name is file.docx then your a href should be 'yourwebsite.com/assets/file/file.docx'

Comment: I found anything out with hrefing with download.php?file={%=file.name%} than I get a GET variable which I can use to download.. But any other help is really welcome :)

Comment: No... you should do like that.. You should point the exact file name like this i.e., `<a href="yourwebsite.com/file/file.doc">Click here to download</a>`